# How to disable 3rd party keyboard use in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, custom-keyboard

Flutter masters!

Is there a way to forbid (disable) usage of a third party keyboard (any custom keyboard) in a Flutter app? I want to be able to use ONLY the system soft keyboard.

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable iOS 3rd party keyboard but not Android
because Android count everything as 3rd party keyboard

to disable in iOS, go to AppDelegate and add this line into Xcode

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
        return extensionPointIdentifier != .keyboard
}
```

to disable in Android, there is no way to disable it unless you create your own keyboard in the app.

Answer (score 1):

The type of extensionPointIdentifier is now `UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier`.

To precise, add this line after the original `override func application` in the AppDelegate file.

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
                return extensionPointIdentifier != .keyboard
        }
```